# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (model) specified for Post

Tags: python, django, django-models

**These are the py files** (error says unknown field(s) (model) specified for Post)

**views.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Post
from .forms import Post_form
# Create your views here.

#def home(request):
#    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'article_details.html'

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = Post_form
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    #fields = '__all__'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets, ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class Post_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','title_tag', 'model', 'body')
         
    widgets = {
        'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'title_tag' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'author' : forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'title' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
    }
```

**models.py**

```
from typing import ChainMap
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.fields import CharField
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #Delete Post when User is deleted
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author) #returns 'title | author' in admin page

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article_detail", args=(str(self.id)))
```

**Error**

```
File "/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import AddPostView, ArticleDetailView, HomeView
  File "/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import Post_form
  File "/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Post_form(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/models.py", line 276, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (model) specified for Post
```

I am new to django and still learning. Stuck here from quite long as the error message here is confusing. Any solutions?
YouTube link which i am referring to - https://youtu.be/6-XXvUENY_8
Edit - models.py added

Comment: Add your model, so we can help

Comment: edited and added models.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `class Post(models.Model)` doesn't have field with name `model`

From your model form

```
fields = ('title','title_tag', 'model', 'body')
```

Your Post model class should look like

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = ...
    title_tag = ...
    model = ... # HERE
    body = ...
```

So either make sure the field exists or remove 'model' from fields `tuple`

Comment: Use this -> fields = ('title', 'title_tag', 'body')

Answer (score 0):

```
fields = ('title','title_tag', 'model', 'body')
```

you need to add the 'model' in field to your Model fields

soo

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = 
    title_tag = 
    model = 
    body =
```